# loopback async/await UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning issue

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, loopbackjs, loopback

In loopback 3 When i implement async/await in the before save Operation hook

```
Entry.observe('before save', async (ctx, next) =>{

    if(ctx.instance.images){
        Entry.upload(ctx.instance.images[0].src).then(data => {
            ctx.instance.image = data;
        });
    }
});
```

the console print this error

```
(node:29323) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Callback was already called.
(node:29323) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How can i get rid of this issue!?

**PS.** i cant figure out where's that promise, and this message disappear once i remove the async/await.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify .catch for the Entry.upload promise.

```
Entry.upload(ctx.instance.images[0].src).then(data => {
        ctx.instance.image = data;
    }).catch(console.error);
```

Some older versions of NodeJS probably won't have that error. You need to always use catch for promises, otherwise the app will crash.

Comment: the same issue, also i removed that block its all about the `async` when i remove it the error just disappear ...

Comment: @dyaa put a try in that async function, just before `if(ctx.instance.images)`, it seems like the error is somewhere there, is ctx.instance defined?

Answer (score 1):

Use `try/catch` block and always return a Promise resolved or rejected when declare `async` function (or Promise function)

```
Entry.observe('before save', async (ctx) =>{
    try {
      ctx.instance.image = await Entry.upload(ctx.instance.images[0].src)
    } catch(error){
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }

    return Promise.resolve()
});
```